# Bean @Autowired by default in spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm working with SpringFramework and Java. I use Spring xml files to define the flow of the architecture and also the beans that will be used in the Java part.

I have two beans of the same class in my xml file, but they have different arguments for the constructor:

```
<bean id="beanA" class="Class" >
    <constructor-arg><value>valueA1</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><value>ValueA2</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="beanB" class="Class" >
     <constructor-arg><value>valueB1</value></constructor-arg>
     <constructor-arg><value>valueB2</value></constructor-arg>-->
</bean>
```

Is there a way to set one of the beans as default in order to `@Autowired` it from Java? And, when I want to use the non default bean, apply the `@Qulifier("beanName")` annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `primary` attribute, eg

```
<bean id="b1" class="test.B" />
<bean id="b2" class="test.B" />
<bean id="b3" class="test.B" primary="true" />
```

this guarantees that b3 bean will be injected here

```
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    B b;
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the awnser. Finally I used another solution, but I'm going to take note of yours, because is simplier than the one of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used a the next thing: I have a setter (`setClassValue(Class classValue)`) in the java code for the class I want to use. Then, I set the property `autowire-candidate` to `false` in the `bean` that it's not going to be the default one:

```
<bean id="beanA" class="Class" autowire-candidate="false">
    <constructor-arg><value>valueA1</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg><value>valueA2</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="beanB" class="Class" >
     <constructor-arg><value>valueB1</value></constructor-arg>
     <constructor-arg><value>valueB2</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then, in the `xml` file where I'm defining the bean of the class that is going to `@Autowired` the `Class`, I use the java `setClassValue(Class classValue)` method on this way:

```
<bean id="classThatAutowire" class="ClassThatAutowire" >
    <property name="classValue" ref="beanA" />
</bean>
```

In the Java code yo will have `@Autowired` the `beanB` and then, set the `beanA`. It's not the best practice, but it works.